# IE&/IE8 issues when loading a hover over link

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

In IE& and IE8 , when i click on a hover over link , it just flashes and then disappears . It is not even staying for a second . Can someone help and suggest a fix ?

Comment: Please publish the code segment with its CSS/style details? This will help others to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you using anchor within li element you should have them both with, if it's only a link give it display, height and width properties via CSS.

```
    display:block;
    height:xpx;
    width:xpx;
```

This is happens because you probably do not hover over text inside of anchor but somewhere near while IE kind of browsers render anchor which has :hover pseudo class only on text once there is no size and display properties.